# .NET Core WebAPI IIS Deploying

Tags: iis, .net-core, webapi

I have created a webAPI using .Net Core and trying to publish it to IIS. But getting HTTP 500.19.
It's looking for web.config file but I don't have it.
What should I do?

Comment: Then how did you publish it? There must be a web.config if you follow the official guide.

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-3.1

If Yes check your permissions on the folder. The identity under which your web application runs in IIS may has not full access to the folder in which the web.config file is found. You could change your identity under the appPool or grant access to your folder. If you deployed into the wwwroot folder the IUser should have access to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your .net core in IIS please remember to install .net core web hosting bundle because it is not supported by default. IIS handle request based on different handlers. Even when you install the extension, aspnet core module is not registered. So please remember to set

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\myapp.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

If the solution doesn't fix this. Then something in your web.config is corrupting the application. Please post a screenshot the detailed error message. Then we would know how to fix this completely.